# What does sleep 0 do in a shell script and what does it do if it used in the ansible SSH config to append after each command?

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, ansible

What does `sleep 0` do in a shell script? I read the man page for sleep and it says "delay for a specified amount of time" And the argument NUMBER specifies this time in SECONDS (by default).

But I see ansible using `sh -c 'echo ~ec2-user && sleep 0'` to start with each task.
Also, it uses this at the end of each remote command it is firing.

I didn't find any special case mention of sleep 0 on the man page and based on the functionality of the `sleep` command it doesn't make any sense to have sleep 0.

The `sleep` command on my server is from `GNU coreutils 8.22`

After looking into this for some more time, here are few things that I have learned,

1. this is a SSH configuration given to the ansible,
2. each time ansible using SSH to execute a task it is running SSH with -C with multiple options. These are not part of playbook or task.
3. I looked for ansible configuration on ansible page [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html). Checked all files and Env variables but found nothing related to ssh
4. Checked the `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` there are not all the parameters/arguments that I see in the SSH that ansible is doing
5. In the inventory as well the host is mentioned just like this
   ansible_host=localhost ansible_user=ec2-user

e.g. log lines at the beginning when ansible executes any task:

```
 <localhost> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="ec2-user"' -o C
onnectTimeout=120 -o ControlPath=/home/ec2-user/.ansible/cp/6bc5a26ee4 localhost '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~ec2-user && sleep 0'"'"''
<localhost> (0, '/home/ec2-user\n', '')
<localhost> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: ec2-user
```

I'm executing an ansible playbook written by one team, there is no one in that team I can talk to. I'm struggling to find where Ansible is taking all these arguments it is using in each SSH and why is it using this `sleep 0`

Comment: Indeed, it does nothing.  If you want to know why ansible is including it, that's a separate question.

Comment: It looks like some attempt to make the exit status of a command zero whether or not `echo ~ec2-user` succeeds. As to why it uses `sleep 0` instead of `true` or `:`, I have no idea.

Comment: Also, I assume you mean a particular Ansible *playbook*, not Ansible itself, using this. This would be a question for whoever wrote the playbook.

Comment: FWIW, read the [comment](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/action/__init__.py#L1225) and see the [issue](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/13876).

Comment: And so the commit adding the lines raised by @VladimirBotka says a little bit (but not much) more: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/commit/bad293ae3537a9d951636b571c8b74df6d8a12b0; *This should minimize loss of stdout when using a pty and connecting with ssh or paramiko_ssh.*

Comment: @chepner it is ansible itself. If I run ansible-playbook I assume ansible is executing the tasks in the background. For an user ansible is declarative so if I just provide a definition of play with a bunch of tasks. Ansible goes in the background uses SSH to connect to the hosts in the inventory and uses the modules and takes the actions.

Comment: @VladimirBotka thanks for your response. I got an answer to my main question. I amended my question to put it in context better. Now I'm wondering where the ansible is taking configuration for SSH from. I have also modified the tags to classify the question it better. If necessary I may split and create another question for 2nd part related to ansible config.

Comment: See [ssh](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/ssh_connection.html) connection plugin. This is [SO offtopic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Proceed in [sf].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see Ansible using `sh -c 'echo ~ec2-user && sleep 0'` to start with each task. Also, it uses this at the end of each remote command it is firing. Apparently this is configured in your project, it's not normal Ansible behaviour.

These commands print the home directory path **and if that succeeds**  `sleep 0` waits zero seconds and exits.

**I doubt that you need this code nowadays.**

The [reference to the race-condition](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/13876) that this is supposed to be a workaround for seems outdated.